# Is it possible to login and download text from an existing website on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, authentication

These days I am thinking about an idea I had for a new `iOS` app. This app should be able to login in to an account on existing website and then "download" all the possible data available from the user profile page and transform it in an `NSString` and then in to a `UILabel` to display it on the device screen. The data I want to download are **only text** and not images or other elements. Let's say this app should be able to StackOverflow, go to my personal profile page and take, for example, my current reputation points number and set it to a `NSString`. Is that possible? If yes, could that be possible even without any (public or private) API available for that very website?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You'd probably want to hit up services that have that type of API support. That's the easiest way in my mind.

Comment: what exactly, you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I would like to make an iOS app for a website which doesn't have one, but without API. This app should be able to login to that website and the get a few text label and transform them in to UILabels

Comment: @Tsvi Tannin Can you explain better?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might wrap(get) the response as HTML page and parse.....   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I was thinking that you could hit up any website with a supporting API with your credentials and request what data you want. Otherwise you would need to design a service that would crawl sites and get the info that you want and should probably be implemented in something other than iOS and then pass that data down through your own DB or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

Without ani API you can use a NSURLSession ([Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)) to authenticate and download your pages.

Then you have to parse the data using some NSRegularExpression to extract the bits you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please post some code and/or some link with a tutorial or something like that?